# Deploying specific docker services locally when running docker-compose with ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have a docker-compose.yml file that deploys several services to AWS ECS. This works fine. However, there are some services that I don't want deployed to ECS. I would like for these docker containers to run locally instead WHILE the other services are deployed on AWS ECS.

I can't find any documentation on this. What settings would I have to set in my docker-compose.yml file so that a specific service is built and run locally instead of being deployed to AWS ECS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create two separate `docker-compose.yaml` files. One could be called `local-only-compose.yaml` or something. When running locally you can pass multiple compose YAML files to `docker-compose`. When deploying to AWS you could pass only the file with the services you want to deploy to ECS.

Comment: Appreciate the response! However, this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for docker compose to run both local instances and deploy ECS all at the same time in one command. To think of it this way, I have a single docker-compose.yaml file that contains both local and deployable services. I need docker compose to handle both type of services correctly.

Comment: Can you provide more info on passing multiple compose YAML files to docker-compose? Would it be possible for me to pass in a compose file that runs local docker instances as well as another compose file that deploys the appropriate ECS instances in a single command like you mentioned? I think that solution can work for me.

Comment: What you want isn't possible. When you switch docker-compose contexts you are switching from local to AWS/ECS context. You can't have multiple contexts active at the same time.  I also don't understand why you would want to do that. Why do you want your AWS infrastructure to be coupled to some local things on your laptop? How are those services connected in any way?

Comment: These local services are designed to do one-off tasks such as database migrations. I'm a novice (1+ week) at devops as well we docker and docker-compose so I'm having a difficult time piecing together the correct way to do this. Thanks for your help and answer. I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Docker containers on your laptop shouldn't have access to your database on AWS, so they shouldn't be able to perform DB migrations. It sounds like you may need a CI/CD platform like AWS CodePipeline.

Comment: Thanks! As of now I am abandoning Docker Compose but will consider this in the future.